# close button under selection in gojs selected node

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a gojs diagram with node selection enabled. The area is specified as

```
$(go.Node, 'Spot', new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify), new go.Binding("key", "_id"),{
        deletable: false,
        selectionObjectName: "mainPanel"
}
```

I also enabled the close button with

```
$diagram = graph.createDiagram('diagram', {
    .........
    enableCloseBtn: true
});
```

The problem is that selection is upon close button which is very irritating. Besides the link also does not look completed.

[image]

Anyone able to help resolve this visual issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered at the duplicate question https://forum.nwoods.com/t/close-button-under-selection-in-gojs-selected-node

What you are seeing happens because the selection Adornment is a separate Part that is intentionally in front of all Nodes and Links, so that it is not obscured by anything inside those nodes or links or by any other nodes or links.

The easy solution is to remove the setting of Part.selectionObjectName in your template. That way the selection handle will surround the whole node, including the red-circle-X button.

But if that is not satisfactory to you, the problem is that the selection Adornment is a separate Part from the selected Node, so it must be drawn entirely after (or before) the whole Node. It cannot be drawn after some objects in the node and before some other objects in the same node.

One solution is not to use selection adornments at all. Set Part.selectionAdorned to false and use a Binding whose source is the Part.isSelected property to control the appearance of some object in your node template. Read about this in https://gojs.net/latest/intro/selection.html1, especially the section about "Selection Appearance Changes".